# I need help on this Golang web application using mysql as database

Tags: mysql, templates, go

I am new to Golang  and had been following some tutorials and I want to put into practice what I have learned to create a website
This is the main.go file

```
package main

import (
        "html/template"
        "net/http"
        "log"
        "database/sql"
        _"github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

//Fetch all templates
var templates, templatesErr = template.ParseGlob("templates/*")
 func main() {
  PORT  := ":9000"
  log.Println("Listening to port", PORT)
  http.HandleFunc("/", root)
  http.HandleFunc("/facilities", allFacilities)
  http.ListenAndServe(PORT, nil)

}
func root(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    rootData := make(map[string]string)
    rootData["page_title"]  = "iSpace Open Data"
    rootData["body"]    = ""

    templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index.html", rootData)
}

 type facility struct{
   FacilityName string
   Type string
 }

func allFacilities(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
  db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:08swanzy@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/iod")
  if err !=nil{
    log.Fatal(err)
  }
  defer db.Close()
  rows, err := db.Query("Select FacilityName, Type from health_facilities ")
  if err != nil {
      log.Fatal(err)
  }
  defer rows.Close()

  fac := facility{}
  facilities := []facility{}
  for rows.Next(){
    var FacilityName, Type string
    rows.Scan(&FacilityName, &Type)
    fac.FacilityName= FacilityName
    fac.Type= Type
    facilities = append(facilities, fac)
  }
  templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "facilities.html", facilities)
}
```

This uses html files in templates folder for the view. But I  keep on getting runtime error saying it has pointer dereference. I need help please.

Comment: on which line does the error occur?

Comment: The stack trace output will tell you _exactly_ where the error is. What line in your code is panicking, and what was the call stack?

Comment: Check if you have templates/index.html in the same directory where main.go is present.

Comment: It shows runtime error of memory address deferencing which does not tell me the line of the code that has the problem. @JimB

Comment: The templates and the main.go are in the same directory. but the index.html is in the template which makes it have different directory from the main.go @KishoreVaishnav

Comment: @olivermensah: the stack trace will always tell you where the dereference happened. My guess is that since you never check `templatesErr`, `templates` is nil. Check your errors first.

Comment: This is what came after making the changes to  the file.  C:/go/src/net/http/server.go:2137 +0x455
2016/07/18 15:19:14 http: panic serving [::1]:55148: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
goroutine 10 [running]:
net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc0820a6e00)
        C:/go/src/net/http/server.go:1389 +0xc8
panic(0x7e5600, 0xc082002080)
        C:/go/src/runtime/panic.go:443 +0x4f7
html/template.(*Template).lookupAndEscapeTemplate(0x0, 0x874810, 0xa, 0x0, 0x0,

Comment: @olivermensah find similar text in the stack trace output "main.go:" which will help you to find the line number. BTW, is your facilities.html is also present in the templates folder? What is the url you are browsing?

Comment: Now  I have been able to fix the runtime error, it was from how the templates were parsed without checking for errors. t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried your code and got the same error. It happened on this line:

```
templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index.html", rootData)
```

The problem is that your templates are not loaded correctly. I moved template parsing to the main function and it works. Here the relevant code snippet:

```
//Fetch all templates
var (
    templates *template.Template
)

func main() {
    var err error
    templates, err = template.ParseGlob("templates/*")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    PORT := ":9000"
    log.Println("Listening to port", PORT)
    http.HandleFunc("/", root)
    http.HandleFunc("/facilities", allFacilities)
    http.ListenAndServe(PORT, nil)

}
```